# HeapAlloc vs "{ }" to zero-fil a struct, Which is better?

Tags: c++, struct

I have a struct with about 30 members. I got this source on internet and I'm optimizing it (A source of a game emulator). But my question is I have always used a struct like this:

```
MY_STRUCT myStruct = {};
myStruct.a = 5;
myStruct.name = "name";
[..]
```

But on this source I got something strange, like this:

```
MY_STRUCT* myStruct = (MY_STRUCT*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(),HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,sizeof(MY_STRUCT));
```

So my question is, is it really needed to use heap alloc for a struct or it's better just to initialize it using `{}`? I use Visual Studio 2012 (C++).

Which is better in terms of performance or best pratices?

Comment: Dynamic allocation is useful if you want to return the struct to the caller function (in which case, an automatic object go out of scope and as such, using a returned pointer pointing to it is UB).

Comment: @H2CO3 though generally if you return by value the copy will be elided

Comment: @aaronman Not sure how that's related.

Comment: You're comparing apples to oranges. The first example has a variable with automatic storage duration, while you're dynamically allocating it in the second. Also, do you need `HeapAlloc` instead of plain old `malloc` or `new`?

Comment: @Praetorian, This app is for Windows only and using HeapAlloc with HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, it'll alloc and initialize this struct. Also as i'm using High level function, if Microsoft would use a better way on futher implementations API, I dont need to change anything...

Comment: @Afonso `malloc` + `memset` or `calloc` will also allocate and zero-initialize the struct. So does `new T()` for PODs. I doubt any of these are slower than `HeapAlloc`. And you have your back compatibility hat on backwards. Using `malloc` or `new`, which are part of the standard library, is a lot bigger guarantee that you won't need code changes in the future, as opposed to using a WinAPI call (although I admit there's almost zero chance MS will get rid of HeapAlloc)

Comment: @Praetorian: `malloc()` + `memset()` is often slower than `calloc()`, since they have to do more work in the case where the memory is already zeroed.  I think the speed of `new T()` would depend on the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first case allocates a structure on a *stack*, not a heap. This is stack allocation, as opposed to the *dynamic allocation*. In particular you have to take the responsibility to free dynamically allocated objects, whereas stack-allocated ones are cleaned up themselves (in a C, not C++ sense).

Performance-wise, stack allocation is almost always faster than dynamic allocation (you only move the stack pointer as opposed to search for and select/annotate a slab in a heap, potentially calling the VMM) but it puts some limitations on object size and of course on it's lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Optimization is tricky because the compiler can do a lot behind the scenes to optimize code for you.  A lot of times it comes out about the same.

In this case, though, it appears the first block of code is allocated on the stack while the second is allocating memory on the heap and returning a pointer, so it's actually doing two different things.  If it's heap allocation you're after, the second one is probably faster only because it's setting everything to 0.